# Сортировка списка со своими объектами по нескольким полям

Tags: c#

Есть свой класс MyClass:

```
public class MyClass
    {
        public MyClass(string name, int index1, int index2, int index3)
        {
            Name = name;
            Index11 = index1;
            Index12 = index2;
            Index13 = index3;
        }

        internal string Name { get; set; }
        internal int Index1{ get; set; }
        internal int Index2 { get; set; }
        internal int Index3 { get; set; }
    }
```

и список:

```
private List<MyClass> MyList= new List<MyClass>();
```

Мне нужен метод, который бы сортировал в начале по Index1, затем по Index2 и в самом конце по Index3. Я пробовал так, но не работает, не знаю где ошибаюсь

```
         private void Sort()
    {
             MyList.OrderBy(x => x.Index1).ThenBy(x => x.Index2).ThenBy(x => x.Index3).ToList();

    }
```

Comment: Можете добавить в вопрос тестовые данные, на которых эта сортировка не работает?

Comment: Приведите пример входных данных и ожидаемый результат

Comment: Ах, ну да, результат сортировки никуда не сохраняется же

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас есть 2 варианта:

1. Присвоить результат написанного вами выражения списку:

   ```
   private void Sort()
   {
        MyList = MyList.OrderBy(x => x.Index1).ThenBy(x => x.Index2).ThenBy(x => x.Index3).ToList();
   }
   ```
2. Отсортировать результаты методом Sort (если нельзя выполнить присвоение):

   ```
   myList.Sort(Compare);

   static int Compare(MyClass x, MyClass y)
   {
       // добавить проверку на null по вкусу

       var result = x.Index1 - y.Index1;

       if (result == 0)
       {
           return Compare2(x, y);
       }

       return result;
   }

   static int Compare2(MyClass x, MyClass y)
   {
       var result = x.Index2 - y.Index2;

       if (result == 0)
       {
           return x.Index3 - y.Index3;
       }

       return result;
   }
   ```